# MediaElement: Force a flash player on users unless they need fall back?

Tags: javascript, media-player, mediaelement

How do you force a flash player on users unless they need fall back?
I need a specific flash player to deliver audio, eg the 1pixelout audio player.
How do i specify that as the audio player, unless they need the other players.

https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement

Comment: This appears to be two quite different questions, and you should split off the second one.

Comment: ok i got an answer to the playlist so ignore it, can i have answer to the first?